# Zabbix, page contents, transparent proxying to another server

Tags: mysql, apache, nginx, proxy, zabbix

There's a page screens.php with severe content. How can I take this page from another server without in-browser redirect? I've made it already trough nginx location directive: fail, it redirects whole page; thru rewrite rule from apache: doesn't work also. Can I do this with web-proxy or not?
Proxying on application level should help, f.e. to split mysql read/write requests, but we have two databases, while zabbix can't work with 2.

Comment: I'd probably just wget-mirror it from crontab. Much simpler.

Comment: Could you explain pls?

Comment: I mean what I should wget. Other DB must be used. Two DBs, 1st more loaded, 2nd, slave, must serve this. There were 2 ways, configure to ask full php page from other server w/o redirect, or application-level proxying. Both don't work.

Comment: Do you want a page people can interact with, or a static (well, updating periodically) page? If the latter, wget/curl the screen and just host that - much simpler than any other option.